# Active voice or Passive to tell general truth

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I have some confusion with below below sentences Constructions.

Que : Should I use Active voice or Passive voice?

a) Wisdom always comes from the most unexpected and undesirable source. (Active Voice)

b) Wisdom is always comes from the most unexpected and undesirable source. (Passive Voice)

According to me both are correct.

Sentence a) gives idea of general present tense.

Sentence b) is defining wisdom. like,

What is wisdom?

Wisdom is something which always comes from ........

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is correct in the Active Voice. Your second sentence is wrong. You cannot write: **Wisdom is always comes ........** The construction **is..comes** is not possible.

If you wished to turn the sentence around in order to use the Passive Voice, you would need to use another verb, as in:

> Wisdom is always obtained/derived from.....

Neither of your sentences defines wisdom. They merely inform us where it comes from without telling us what it is.

As for telling a general truth, you can use either the Active or Passive Voice.

Active Voice:

> Actions speak louder than words

Passive Voice:

> Many a truth is spoken in jest.

https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-active-and-passive-voice.html

Comment: @ Ronald Sole, I have read so may sentences using **Is..comes**. E.g. 1) Experience is always comes from the lessons we have learned. 2) The true beauty is always comes from a pure heart, 3)  Dumb is Always Comes Before Smart. etc.

Comment: @user4084 Whoever wrote those sentences had very little knowledge of English grammar. Believe me, they are simply wrong. In both your examples, you need to omit the word **is**.